# Правило eslint не работает для отступов props в RFC

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Не могу найти правило, которое будет правильно линтировать (форматировать) пропсы передаваемые в компонент или функцию, ниже пример того как это выглядит сейчас, то есть отступ у пропсов (`query` и `data`) слева очень большой

```
export const apiPostQwerty = async ({
                                         query,
                                         data
                                     }) => {
    const url = `/api/qwerty/${query}`
    const response = await misc.post(url, data)

    return response.data
}
```

Хотелось бы настроить это так, чтобы было:

```
export const apiPostQwerty = async ({
    query,
    data
}) => {
    const url = `/api/qwerty/${query}`
    const response = await misc.post(url, data)

    return response.data
}
```